# How to add scrollbar to panel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jscrollpane, jscrollbar

I need help.  I have one panel which can need to have width 1000px. I need to add lot of buttons with different size ( I add with flow layout and it works fine). Problem is that I have height on screen example 500px but when I add buttons panel has bigger size. How to add scrollbar to panel ?

Comment: how about reacting to the answers/comments to your previous questions around panel layout in a JScrollPane? Plus read the tutorial links you were given, pleaase

Comment: 199 questions & only 6 answers.

Answer (score 5):

Add your panel to scrollpane and add that pane where you are adding your panel instead of panel

```
JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
```