# adding a scrollbar to a jPanel

Tags: java, size, scrollbar, jpanel, draw

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to add scrollbar to panel ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5790525/how-to-add-scrollbar-to-panel)

I'm trying to draw some shapes on a jPanel, once the shapes reach the panel size, the rest of shapes are not visibles.
can I add a scrollbar to the panel in order to see the rest of the shapes?

Comment: @CoolBeans, @skaffman, @Neal, @Andrew Thompson, @Michael Petrotta - Why do people keep closing questions even though they don't understand the question?? This question has nothing to do with the "How to add scrollbar to panel" question. Custom painting is completely different compared to adding components to a panel and the solution is not the same as was suggested in the other posting. If you think the question is a duplicate, then give the link and let the poster decide.

Comment: When you add components to a panel, the layout manager will give the panel a preferred size. When you do custom painting there are no components on the panel so there is no preferred size. Therefore you are responsible for setting the preferred size of the panel so the scrollpane can do its job properly.

Answer (score 0):

Sure: wrap your `JPanel` into a `JScrollPane` (it takes any `Component` in its constructor)